# Pandas df.str.split() on first element only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a column in a dataframe with chat conversations of which the general format in each cell is:

'*name agent* *:* *conversation*'

I would like to create a new column that contains only the *conversation* part.

I did that using the following code:

```
filtered_transcript_text['msgText'].str.split(':', expand = True)
```

However, this function creates a split for each occurrence rather than only for the first one. Is there a way of using the *split* function for only the first occurence of an instance?

I am aware that I could merge the other created columns, however this seems devious to me.

Comment: Use `.str.partition(':')` instead? That's generally faster than using `.str.split(':', expland=True, n=1)` and is more stable depending if the delimiter is present or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with add `n=1`

```
filtered_transcript_text['msgText'].str.split(':', expand = True,n=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

```
.str.split(pat=":", n=1, expand=True)
```